# H-Geometry in Python

Tags: python, module, geometry, trigonometry

Is there any Python module for H-Geometry trigonometric functions? It would be pretty easy to write them, but I'd prefer to avoid it, especially if there is an existing better implementation out there.

I looked through the Python math library, but it doesn't have these functions.

Comment: It sounds interesting, but this is rather obscure mathematics. I'd be surprised if you found a library implementation anywhere.

Comment: This appears to be some guy who chose to define an arbitrary geometric construct, wrote a book about it, and is now trying to draw some attention. This very SO question was the 3rd google result for me. Turns out h = sin(theta)/(sin(theta)+cos(theta)) but they really try to avoid stating the relationship. This is not mainstream mathematics at all and the question (and answer) smells of advertising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote incomplete library for H-Geometry, but decided to push it only now. It can be found at https://github.com/simukis/H-Geometry

Answer (score 0):

Look into `numpy`, if you're doing numerical calculations of any sort.  E.g. [`numpy.sinh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sinh.html), [`numpy.tanh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tanh.html), [`np.cosh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cosh.html), etc.

Comment: These are hyperbolic, not h-geometrical. I've run through documentation, but still didn't found any mentions to h-geometry or sph, cph, tph (h-geometry function names for sin, cos and tan).

Comment: @nagisa - Ah, sorry, I assumed by "H-Geometry" that you meant hyperbolic.  I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean by "H-Geometry", then...

Comment: @nagisa - Did you, by chance, mean hypergeometric functions?  There are implementations in `scipy.special`, if so... http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#hypergeometric-functions

Comment: I don't think so. These h-geometry functions are just another functions to find sine, cosine and tangent but not from radians or degrees. There's another unit showing size of angle - h. It's counted by specific formula(just like degrees to radians conversion). Worst thing that all I know about it is only name and 7 formulas.

Comment: I guess you mean something like this then? http://www.rdi.lt/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=58&Itemid=51&limitstart=1  I'd never head of it until I started googling... I'm afraid I can't help too much, though like you said, it shouldn't be too hard to implement from scratch. Good luck!